# Complex ordering of Entity Relationships in Symfony2/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm attempting to setup a simple forum viewer for an existing database. Mainly as an exercise in learning Symfony2.

As with most forums it has some interlinked things. Mostly in a chain like this:

```
Forum -> Thread -> Comment -> Author
```

I have created a schema using annotations that describes a *OneToMany* relationship between Forum > Thread and between Thread > Comment. Author is *OneToOne* with Thread and Comment.

My issue is that I want to show a list of threads within my forum that is sorted by the timestamp of the most recent comment within each thread (as is normal on forums). This is compounded by the fact I also need to ensure sticky or pinned threads are at the top of the list.

I've been having a go at putting the code in various places but I'm not sure of the best practices place for it. I have attempted a DQL solution within my ForumRepository

```
public function findWithOrderedComments($forum_id)
{
    $forum = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT f,
           (SELECT c.time
                FROM xxForumArchiveBundle:Comment c
                WHERE c.post = p.id
                ORDER BY c.time DESC) AS time
            FROM xxForumArchiveBundle:Forum f 
            JOIN f.posts p
            WHERE f.id = :forum_id
            ORDER BY time')
        ->setParameter('forum_id', $forum_id)
        ->getSingleResult();

    return $forum[0];
}
```

But this (apart from turning my query response into an array) did nothing. I've toyed with putting some sorting logic in the model to return a sorted comments collection but am a) unsure if this is the correct place and b) did nothing to solve my sort order on the forum page. I've also thought of doing it in the twig template but that seems wrong to me. I could also do it in the controller but given that Doctrine has already loaded the data(?) I'm fairly certain thats a waste.

In my twig template I'm basically doing `{% for post in forum.posts %}`.

How do I get this done?